# Rationale behind prefix-closure in CSP trace semantics

Tags: concurrency, semantics, formal-methods, process-algebras

I'm currently studying Hoare's "Communicating Sequential Processes" (1) and I've come across a concept that I find a bit puzzling. In CSP trace semantics, a process's semantics are described by a subset of finite execution traces that is prefix-closed.

The need to indicate a complete computation introduces the 'tick' event $\checkmark$. This event, unlike ordinary ones, should only occur at the end of a trace, and creates exceptional preconditions for different program constructs.

Most seriously, the parallel combination is no longer a totally defined binary operation in the presence of 'tick' (section 5.3.1, p159):

"...We therefore need to impose alphabet constraints on parallel composition. $(P || Q )$ must be regarded as invalid unless
$\alpha P \subseteq \alpha Q \lor \alpha Q \subseteq \alpha P \lor \checkmark \in (\alpha P \cap \alpha Q \cup \alpha P \cap \alpha Q )$"

I'm trying to understand the underlying logic for this complexity. Why must the semantics of a process includes its non-terminated traces and require prefix-closure, instead of simply including terminated traces? What would be the implications if only terminated traces were considered?

1. Hoare, C. A. R. (1985). Communicating Sequential Processes.
   Prentice Hall. ISBN 978-0-13-153289-2. http://www.usingcsp.com/cspbook.pdf